# count nonzero values in each column tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, summarize

I have a df with a bunch of sites and a bunch of variables. I need to count the number of non-zero values for each site. I feel like I should be able to do this with `summarize()` and `count()` or `tally()`, but can't quite figure it out.

reprex:

```
df <- 
  tribble(
    ~variable,   ~site1,   ~site2,  ~site3,
    "var1",        0 ,       1,        0,
    "var2",        .5,       0,        0,
    "var3",        .1,       2,        0,
    "var4",        0,        .8,       1
  )


# does not work:
df %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ count(.x>0)))
```

desired output:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  site1 site2 site3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   2     3     1
```

Comment: Use `sum()` not `count()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("site"), ~ sum(.x != 0)))

#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   site1 site2 site3
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     2     3     1
```

---

Another possible solution, in base R:

```r
apply(df[-1], 2, \(x) sum(x != 0))

#> site1 site2 site3 
#>     2     3     1
```

Comment: OP's looking for non-zero values.

Comment: Thanks for calling my attention to that, @Maël! I have just updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

In base R, you can use `colSums`:

```r
colSums(df[-1] > 0)

#> site1 site2 site3 
#>     2     3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` option using `purrr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df[,-1] %>% 
  map_dbl(~sum(. != 0))

# site1 site2 site3 
#   2     3     1
```

Or an option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

as.data.table(df[,-1])[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x!=0))]

#   site1 site2 site3
#1:     2     3     1
```